# Entity Framework: Data Centric vs. Object Centric

Tags: entity-framework

I'm having a look at Entity Framework and everything I'm reading takes a data centric approach to explaining EF.  By that I mean that the fundamental relationships of the system are first defined in the database and objects are generated that reflect those relationships.

**Examples**

[Quickstart (Entity Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217655/using-entity-framework-entities-as-business-objects)

[Using Entity Framework entities as business objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217655/using-entity-framework-entities-as-business-objects)

The EF documentation implies that it's not necessary to start from the database layer, e.g.

> Developers can work with a consistent
>   application object model that can be
>   mapped to various storage schemas

When designing a new system (simplified version), I tend to first create a class model, then generate business objects from the model, code business layer stuff that can't be generated, and then worry about persistence (or rather work with a DBA and let him worry about the most efficient persistence strategy).  That object centric approach is well supported by ORM technologies such as (n)Hibernate.

Is there a reasonable path to an object centric approach with EF?  Will I be swimming upstream going that route?  Any good starting points?

Comment: What version of .NET / Entity Framework are you using?  1.0/3.5 or 4.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Model First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/) approach seems to be what you need. 
We suggest to take a look at the [ADO.NET Team Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160604113813/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/11/05/model-first-with-the-entity-framework-4.aspx) article also.

Comment: [Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) is even more appropriate, IMHO

Answer (score 2):

A while after asking this, I discovered that EF 4 supports POCO (Plain Old CLR Objects), allowing an object-centric design with (relative) ignorance of persistence.

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160720214340/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx) was the best one I came across discussing that approach, while [this article](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1457/entity-framework-40-pocofirst-development-and-poco-template.aspx) explains how to use code generation templates to ease the work.