# How best to extend Entity Framework generated POCO objects whilst maintaining the relationships

Tags: c#, architecture, entity-framework-4

I'm working on a project where I've created a core DAL / BLL with the Entity Framework and generating POCO objects. I've created partial classes for the POCO's to contain the core functionality that I want to implement on these base business objects.

The solution is going to be for multiple clients all with slightly different ways of implementing their business logic. I'd like to be able to extend some of the POCO objects to add additional / change current functionality. I want to keep this separate from their core functionality which as I said is defined in the partials.

The problem I have is that if I create an object which extends a POCO object I can only maintain the relationship between the extended object and the original POCO objects it relates too. I need to somehow be able to define the relationship between extended POCO objects.

An example would be if I had a Customers POCO which contained a list of Orders which were also POCOs. Say for some reason I need to customise the Customer class so I create a CustomCustomer class which extends the functionality of Customer. Then for some reason I need to customise the Order class so I create a CustomOrder class which extends the functionality of Order. How do I maintain the relationship between the CustomCustomer and CustomOrders.

I initially thought that the Decorator pattern may be able to help me here but when I started to practically implement it, it seemed like a fair bit of work and I just wanted to see if I was missing something obvious before I continued.

Answer (score 0):

You have two approaches here, depending on what you need:

If your `CustomCustomer` class need to use a `CustomOrder`, but not through custom methods (meaning that you can use it referencing just the `Order` base type), you don't need to keep those new references, Entity Framework take care of that for you, as long you configure the inheritance hierarchy.

It will load the `Orders` list, but some of them will actualy be `CustomOrder`, but on a `Order` list.

On the other hand, if you actually need to use those `CustomOrder`, typed as `CustomOrder` on the `CustomCustomer`, create a property on `CustomCustomer` filtering all the `Orders` except the custom ones:

```
public IEnumerable<CustomOrder> CustomOrders
{
    get
    {
        return base.Orders
            // We check the BaseType here because EF creates a derived class of our classes. 
            .Where(o => o.GetType().BaseType == typeof(CustomOrder))
            .Select(o => o as CustomOrder);
    }
}
```

Note that, even on the second approach, you need the inheritance hierarchy configured in EF for this to work.

If none of this work for you, go to the hard route: put `CustomCustomerId` on the `CustomOrder`, have a separate list on `CustomCustomer`, and be ready to live with the fact that if you get all orders witch contain `CustomerId = 1`, you may not have ACTUALLY got all of them...

Answer (score -1):

Your POCO's are *not* business objects.  They're data objects.  If you want to implement business objects, you should create buisness versions of these objects, then copy the data between the data and business objects as needed.  Tools like AutoMapper help with that.

Comment: Thanks for the response but your comment does not answer my question. I also do not agree with your statement or approach.

Comment: @NormanNoble - Well, you're the one having trouble doing something you're not supposed to be doing in the first place.  You can disagree all you want, but you would not be having this problem if you were doing it correctly.  EF objects are not meant to be extended in the way you are trying to do, because they are not the kind of objects you think they are.

Comment: The you'd better go tell this guy that he's wrong:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217655/using-entity-framework-entities-as-business-objects/217657#217657

I'm trying to do this without adding the unnecessary code bloat that an additional layer that simply passes data back and forth would require and if it can't be done I'd like to be told that and a reason why.

Comment: @NormanNoble - Your link is not wrong.  It's *POSSIBLE* to use them as business objects, it's just not a good idea to do so.  One reason is that you can't extend them in the way you are trying to extend them.  EF wraps the POCO's in proxy classes, this is invisible to you and your app.  So when you extend your classes, they can't be managed anymore by EF.

Comment: @NormanNoble - A better way to think of it is that if you use EF entities as your business objects, you must stick to the models that EF knows about.  You can certainly derive from those entities, but you will have no way to map them back into EF.  BTW, are you using POCO's are are you using partial classes extended from EF Entities?  One typically only uses partial classes for compiler generated code, such as the way EF works without POCO's.  If you're using POCO's there's no reason to use partial classes.

Comment: Wow - That's a lot of comment. I'll start at the start. I believe I can extend them the way I want to. The side effect is that I cannot have relationships between extended entities. That will be an architectural decision to make. I believe (and I may be wrong here) that as long as my extended class inherits from the base entity class, the proxy wrapping will still occur. If not then I agree that this would be a bad idea.

I'm happy enough to couple my application to the Entity Framework and I'm happy to work with the model I have.

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.