# ASP.NET MVC / Core and Entity Framework 6 / Core - configuration and validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fluentvalidation, ef-fluent-api

I've been checking out some more new topics for a new ASP.NET MVC / Core project, including EF 6 and EF Core 2.1, in terms of setting up entities and validating them.

The current consensus around defining entities seems to be the Fluent API - either in the `OnModelCreating` overridden method, or by means of separate entity type configuration classes. These look quite compelling and fairly easy to understand and wrap your head around.

For validation, I've been looking at the [Fluent Validation library](https://fluentvalidation.net/) by Jeremy Skinner - which again uses a fluent, code-based approach to handle validation of types. Again - on its own, this looks quite compelling and quite flexible.

My concern is: if I'm using these two technologies together - am I not going to be doing everything twice? First of all, I need to setup and configure my entity types in the EF Fluent API so that EF can map those classes to relational tables, and secondly, I'll be describing almost the same rules again, in the Fluent Validation library, for validation of those entities.

I'm afraid this will be (a) a lot more work than it should be, and (b) will break pretty soon if a change to one of the two "models" is made, and forgotten in the other system.....

Is there a better approach? Can these two approaches be combined somehow? Or am I not seeing how they play together and do not cause any duplication?

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but I feel they serve two different purposes. The first is the configuration of your entities, and FluentValidation is for defining, and enforcing, the validation requirements of your views. Those two concerns typically aren't the same.

Comment: @JohnH: but they will share a lot of common ground, e.g. a column in a database that's `NOT NULL` will also have to be `[Required]` or `.NotNull()` in the validation part. It just seems to me that you'd be doing too many things twice - and run the risk of suddenly updating one part and missing out on the other...

Comment: There may be common ground, but they are two different concerns and really your external contract request/response objects (for which you need to provide `[Required]` validation on the request, for example) should not be the same object as your data entity that you write to the db (which has to satisfy a NOT NULL constraint on your db). It is easy to think of them as the same object though, and sometimes an enforced mapping layer helps break that thinking :)

Comment: @Mashton: so you're advocating using the EF Fluent API for the database entities, while using FluentValidation for non-entity classes - like DTO's, viewmodels etc. ?

Comment: I am, and found a nice description of some of the problems you encounter when you try and use the same entity for data and viewmodel/DTO https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543152/2153329. At one level you want to keep things DRY, but equally when you think about your viewmodels, for example, they will often be annotated with things that are of no concern to a data model (e.g. `[DataContract]`, `[JsonIgnore]`, or some `[CustomAttribute]`). EF does allow this to get blurred by using partial classes ... but still, they _are_ different concerns.

Comment: @Mashton: OK and thanks for that link - things are beginning to clear up a bit slowly! Package your two comments into an answer, and I'm quite likely to accept it :-)